# Optimizing Pandas Seeded SciPy Operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Is there anyway to speed up a per row scipy `rvs` method call that relies on a specific seed?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

df = pd.DataFrame({"loc": range(1000), "seed": range(1000)})

def apply_rvs(x):
    np.random.seed(x["seed"])
    return norm.rvs(x["loc"], 1)

%timeit df.apply( lambda x: apply_rvs(x), axis=1)
# 109 ms ± 3.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

numba doesn't seem to play nice with scipy objects

```
import numba

@numba.jit
def numba_apply_rvs(x):
    np.random.seed(x["seed"])
    return norm.rvs(x["loc"], 1)

df.apply( lambda x: numba_apply_rvs(x), axis=1)
```

> Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "apply_rvs" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'norm': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'scipy.stats._continuous_distns.norm_gen'>

Besides parallelization, are there any other approaches I can take to speed this operation up?

It would be nice if I could make one call to generate all these values similar to

```
In [33]: norm.rvs([1,2,3,4],[.1,.1,.1,.1])                                                         
Out[33]: array([0.93510993, 2.15662676, 2.79086298, 4.14563281])
```

but unfortunately `random_state` cannot be passed as an array.

Comment: is there a reason you want random numbers generated from different seeds?

Comment: it's used in a testing process that needs to generate the same data for each row consistently, hence the need for a seed.  I don't want each row to have the same data, so I can't use a fixed seed either

Comment: Fixing the seed at the start will still return a quasi-random sequence of draws from `rvs()`.  Setting the seed every draw is highly unusual

Comment: The basic idea is the code will run once and generate `person_id_1 time_1 value_1`, then run again later to generate `person_id_1 time_1 value_1, person_id_1 time_2 value_2`

I want `value_1` in each case to be the same, so I use the `person_id` as the seed.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many moving parts --- pandas, numba, scipy.stats --- some more work us needed to where the bottleneck is. E.g. is it pandas or is it just generation of the random sample? IOW, you should time the latter without pandas.

If random sampling is the bottleneck, then use the normal distribution from `numpy.random`. Otherwise, look into speeding up the pandas part etc